# Is there a new FirestoreAdminClient to use now when cloud functions are recommended to run on 2nd gen?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When doing data export from Firestore to a bucket I am following the suggested solution on: [Schedule data exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export).

Some cherry-picked code from the solution is as follows:

```
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
...
const projectId = process.env.GCP_PROJECT;
const databaseName = client.databasePath(projectId, '(default)');

return client.exportDocuments({
    name: databaseName,
    outputUriPrefix: bucket,
    collectionIds: []
    })
...
```

Now, with 2nd gen I know that e.g. project Id instead can be picked up using a pre-defined parameters from `firebase-functions/params`

But is there a new `FirestoreAdminClient` that should/could be used to do `databasePath()` and `exportDocuments()` with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The version you're seeing for FirestoreAdminClient (from the node module "@google-cloud/firestore") has nothing to do with the version of Cloud Functions (from the node module "firebase-functions") supported by the Firebase CLI.  They are almost entirely unrelated to each other, except by how you choose to use them in the same project.

[FirebaseAdminClient](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/v1.FirestoreAdminClient.html) from [@google-cloud/firestore](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/module-@google-cloud_firestore.html) has its own documentation on GCP which you can read and understand on its own terms and use anywhere that runs nodejs (including Cloud Functions).

Comment: Ah, I see a difference I'm doing compared to the link I referred.. I'm including in the follwing way: import * as admin from "firebase-admin"; Then using it as   const firestoreAdminClient = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

So that might be wrong then, I guess?

Comment: Okey, I see now. The way I use it refer the same @google-cloud node module. It's all good. Although, I should depend on it directly instead.

Comment: firebase-admin support for Firestore is just a wrapper around @google-cloud/firestore.  They expose exactly the same API.

Answer (score 1):

You will simply require/import (2) Google Node Client Libraries. It should be rather easy to do. One for interacting w Firestore, the other for interacting w Cloud Storage (bucket).

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest

and

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest